# what are the possible choices for the 'Mode=' field in desktop.ini file

Tags: windows-7, desktop.ini

I would like to know what are the possible choices for the 'Mode=' field, I want to keep only one directory with medium icons (my default setting is Details) and I suppose that's the field to set.

Unfortunately there's really no information about this field, not even on the MSDN site...

If someone have some infos I will be glad to see it.

Comment: As there is no information, perhaps it does not do anything. Maybe it's a legacy from Windows 3.11.